# BeautifulSoup extracting text inside td before inner tags

Tags: beautifulsoup

Doing webscraping and and I need to split up a `<td>` content into two variables for database.

```
<td align="left">
  "Text i need to extract first"
  <br>
  <strong title="code">474308972347089374324</strong> #text i need to extract secoond
</td>
```

This section is within a table, within a tr tag with multiple other td tags

Thanks in advance

EDIT

Code as much as I can show

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(destination.content, "lxml")
pakid = soup.find("table", {"class": "aared"})
read = pakid.findAll("tr")
for row in read:
    content = row.findAll("td")
    id = content[0].text # works well
    name = content[1].next_sibling(text=True)
    name = name[0]
```

Next sibling gives a list and I can select either first or second item from te list but it seems messy, any ideas how to make it cleaner?

Comment: Show us what you tried and how you failed and where you need help please.

Comment: Edited original post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution.

```
from simplified_scrapy import SimplifiedDoc, req, utils
html = '''
<table class="aared">
<tr>
<td align="left">
  "Text i need to extract first"
  <br>
  <strong title="code">474308972347089374324</strong> #text i need to extract secoond
</td>
</tr>
</table>
'''
doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
trs = doc.select('table.aared').trs.tds
for tr in trs:
  id = tr[0].firstText()
  name = tr[0].strong.text
  print (id)
  print (name)
```

Result:

```
"Text i need to extract first"
474308972347089374324
```

Comment: Something new and I like it, much cleaner and does the job. Will see how it will work with the rest of logic, thank You!

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you can do something like this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

h = """
    <td align="left">
      "Text i need to extract first"
      <br>
      <strong title="code">474308972347089374324</strong> #text i need to extract secoond
    </td>
    """

soup = BeautifulSoup(h, "lxml")
obj = soup.select_one('td')
print(obj.find(text=True, recursive=False).strip())
print(obj.select_one('strong').text)
```

Comment: Interesting but I cannot make it work for my for loop. I have tens of thousands of tr tags with 6+ tds in each. That solution will not work for me

Comment: If that's the case, then instead of `.select_one`, use `select` all loop through all those elements.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, cannot make Your version work. Sorry for wasting Your time

Comment: I got it working, but the next solution seemed cleaner to me. Thank You for the help